# How to modify the number of decimal places in Angular currency?

Tags: angular

`{{ 10000 | currency:'COP':'':'1.2-2'}}`

Result = 10.000,00

I need to show the decimal places in a small size 10.000,**00**

**Solved**

in the case of serving another person, I solved it as follows

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'myCurrency'
})
export class MyCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }  
  transform(num: any, currencyCode: string, showSymbol: boolean, digits: string): any {
    let value = new CurrencyPipe(navigator.language).transform(num, currencyCode, showSymbol, digits);
    let lastDigit = '<span style="font-size: 80%;">' + value.slice(-3) + '</span>';
    let firstDigit = value.match(/\d/);
    let symbol = value.slice(0, firstDigit.index);
    let amount = value.slice(firstDigit.index);
    let amountLast = symbol +amount.slice(0, -3) + lastDigit;
    const sanitizedContent = DOMPurify.sanitize(amountLast);
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(sanitizedContent);   

  }

}
```

Comment: Decimal is a radix. You mean decimal *places.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a minor typo in your syntax. You can find the correct syntax in the [Angular Currency Pipe Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe#description) docs. Here is what it should look like:

`{{10000 | currency:"COP":"symbol":"1.2-2"}}`

Also here I created a working [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-currency-pipe-xrrr4z?file=app/app.component.html) if you want to play with it.